# Add scope and client application to AAD app via PowerShell script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to create an azure active directory (AAD) application. Here is the command I use:

```
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication    -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName `
                                -AvailableToOtherTenants $false `
                                -ReplyUrls $replyUrls `
                                -RequiredResourceAccess $requiredResourceAccess
```

How do I update the script to add scope and client application?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and exposed an API** by using below commands:

```
$uiAppDisplayName = "rukapptest"
$uiApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $uiAppDisplayName 
$myappId=$uiApp.AppId

Set-AzADApplication -ApplicationId $uiApp.AppId -IdentifierUris "api://$myappId"
```

[image]

In the Portal, **Application ID URI updated successfully** like below:

[image]

To add **scope**, I used the below PowerShell script:

```
$permissionScope = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Powershell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.MicrosoftGraphPermissionScope
$permissionScope.Id = New-Guid
$permissionScope.AdminConsentDescription = "user_impersonation"
$permissionScope.AdminConsentDisplayName = "user_impersonation"
$permissionScope.IsEnabled = $true
$permissionScope.Type = "User" 
$permissionScope.UserConsentDescription = "user_impersonation"
$permissionScope.UserConsentDisplayName = "user_impersonation"
$permissionScope.Value = "user_impersonation"

$api = $app.Api
$api.Oauth2PermissionScope = $permissionScope

Update-AzADApplication -ApplicationId AppID -Api $api
```

[image]

In the Portal, **scope added successfully** like below:

[image]

To **add Authorized client applications,** make use of **`MgGraph`** module like below:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"

az ad app show --id fec4fdf0-c612-4aa9-8560-a187a2d98dc3 --query "oauth2Permissions[].id"

$params = @{
    Api = @{
        PreAuthorizedApplications = @(
            @{
                AppId = "AppID"
                delegatedPermissionIds = @(
                    "PermissionIDgeneratedbyabovecommand"
                )
            }
        )
    }
}

Update-MgApplication -ApplicationId AppObjectID -BodyParameter $params
```

[image]

In the Portal,  **Authorized client applications got added successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: Sorry your images are not clear. What happens in $params? please clarify. What I need to do is add a client id and check an authorized scope

Comment: I have already added the script in text format. In AppID pass the authorizedappClientID and while using Update-MgApplication make use of your Application Object ID.

Comment: and pass this command like `az ad app show --id yourappClientID --query "oauth2Permissions[].id"`

Comment: I'm not the admin of this tenant. So, I'm unable to run Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Application.ReadWrite.All"

Comment: There is no direct az command to add authorised client application. You have to use either MgGraph or Microsoft Graph to achieve your requirement.

Comment: As a workaround login to Microsoft Graph and consent Application.ReadWrite.All permission and try.